# What are secondary vertices and what is Vertex vs Jet

Tags: particle-physics

What is the difference between a vertex and a jet? Are they the same?

Are secondary vertices sort of jets that are part of a larger jet?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Jets are a terminology used descriptively to start with, on collectively seen measured tracks of particles, and it analogous to "a jet of water" a bunch of particles in a direction defined by limited angles.

[image: event]

> [Protons collide](https://home.cern/news/news/experiments/seeing-invisible-event-displays-particle-physics) at 13 teraelectronvolts in this event display from 3 June 2015, sending showers of particles through the CMS experiment (Image: CMS)

The yellow  tracks around the interaction point, depending on the model that is used to fit the data, show three large jets, a higher angular concentration of tracks coming from the vertex, and maybe more smaller energy ones once the measurements are analyzed .

So in the experimental data, tracks come from the vertex, the point of two protons interacting in this case, some of the tracks may be part of jets.

Vertices are also used in describing Feynman diagrams, the pictorial tool of setting up the calculations for the given interaction.

[In this Feynman diagram](http://hyperphysics.phy-astr.gsu.edu/hbase/Particles/expar.html) to calculate electron electron scattering to firs order

[image: ee]

there are two vertices. The first vertex is of the incoming two electrons, the second vertex of the outgoing two electrons.

In this generic Feynman diagram:

[image: generic]

There are four vertices,two secondary.This is a higher order diagram.

Depending on the interaction under study , the last vertex in this  Feynman diagram  may be used to model two jets, jets as defined in the picture above,  going out, i.e. much more complicated interactions modeled simply.

Feynman diagrams can be very complicated, with many outgoing particles ,

[for example](http://ttps://www-d0.fnal.gov/Run2Physics/top/top_public_web_pages/top_feynman_diagrams.html) top anti-top production:

[image: ttbar]

the final outgoing lines of b, b_bar, q, q_bar will be identified in the data with jets of particles.